# Translate boolean flags to collection of numbers in scala

Tags: scala

I'm having trouble to implement the following requirement in a functional way in scala. Given a predefined number of boolean flags, I want to build up a collection of numbers. For each (true) flag, a hardcoded number should be included in the collection.

This is the unsatifying solution I have so far:

```
  def createCodeArray(flagA:Boolean, flagB:Boolean, flagC:Boolean): Seq[Int] = {
    val codes = ListBuffer.empty[Int]

    if(flagA) codes += 2
    if(flagB) codes += 7
    if(flagC) codes += 12

    return codes
  }
```

I'm trying to achieve to same with pattern matching, but I don't want to list all the possible combinations. Also, I'd like to avoid mutable data-structures.

Any suggestion on how to write this in a functional way is much appreciated

Comment: Could you tell us more about where these flags come from, how this method is called, and how the resulting list will be used?

Comment: @200_success this should not matter for this question, the method's functionality and  signature should just remain as it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use tuples to pair your flags with an `Int`. Throw those into a `Seq` and then perform a `filter` and then a `map` on that `Seq`. Here is how that would look:

```
def f(a: Boolean, b: Boolean, c: Boolean): Seq[Int] = {

 val xs = Seq((a, 2), (b, 7), (c, 12))

 xs.filter(t => t._1).map(t => t._2) 

}
```

Note that in Scala you don't need to use a `return` statement as long as the last bit of code in your function returns a new value.

Comment: @thanks, I'm aware that the return statement is not needed, still I'd like to use it to make the code more "speaking"

Comment: @Raphael, sure with `return` statement it is more "speaking", but it is against Scala coding style. A good explanation is given [here](https://github.com/alexandru/scala-best-practices/blob/master/sections/2-language-rules.md).